# How to host 2 virtual hosts on nginx on www subdomains?

Tags: nginx, webserver, subdomain, cname

I am new to all this and trying hard already for 4 days without any big success. Maybe it's just a small thing and hopefully you can help me! Was not able to find an answer here so far (at least nothing worked out until now):

I have a domain, say example.com registered. I also added a subdomain test.example.com and added it as a CNAME to example.com.

Then I installed nginx and set it up following th tutorial on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts with the minor change that I have both servers in one config file by now. In short, it looks like this:

in etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com

```
server {
    listen 80;


    root /var/www/example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}


server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/test.example.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name test.example.com www.test.example.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

example.com works fine and shows me "welcome to example.com" in broswer tab and some text that example.com server is running as expected (defined index.html by me as in the example).

BUT: If I go to test.example.com it shows me in the tab "welcome to example.com" either although it should be "welcome to **test.**example.com" and there is no html page at all shown to me. it's just a blank page.

Can someone help me? I don't know, if I already got the stuff with the cname domain or whether there might be something wrong.

Thank you very muh in advance!:-)

Comment: I just noticed that on example.com the broswer tab shows me "Apache Ubuntu Default Page", but page ist the success message. I had installed Apache before switching to nginx. There might went something wrong when I deinstalled Apache. Will have a look at it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. It was not on the server but a wrong setting in my domain provider. I don't have to forward my domain but just set it in the nameservers instead pointing to the ip!